# File-based database engine

Tags: windows, relational-database, oledb, jet

I'm looking for a relational database engine that complies with the following requirements:

1. **Databases are simple files** like MSAccess databases. You can copy, delete, send them easily just with Windows Explorer. There's no management tool required.
2. **x86 and x64 database providers can coexist on the same machine**. MSAccess meets this criterion if you use the Jet 4.0 database format. Then you can use Windows' built-in *Jet 4.0* (`Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`) for 32 bit access and *Access 2010 Database Engine x64* (`Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`) for 64 bit access. But if Office 2010 is installed in its 32 bit edition, Microsoft prevents you from installing ADE x64. Since many customers actually need Office 2010 x86, switching to the x64 edition is not an option.
3. **Database files can reside on a network share**. Concurrent access is not required, but the engine must be able to open databases that are not local.

Could *SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB* work out?

Access (Jet 4.0) databases comply with most scenarios, but the aforementioned limitation (2.) stands. However, if Microsoft released `Access 2013 Database Engine x64` as a standalone redistributable in future, this might solve this issue. Since Office 2013 introduced the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0` provider, evidence suggests that *Office 2010 x86* and *ADE 2013 x64* actually can coexist. Does anyone know if this will eventually happen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out SQLite? That may be worh a try.